# VBA replacement for worksheets.queryTables

Tags: vba

I am having serious issues with the worksheets.queryTables object as it quite often throws an automation error : the object has disconnected" and I cant fix that. So, instead of dealing with this, I am looking for other good ways to import data from a csv without using this object and without opening the file.
Any suggestions what would be a good alternative?

The server with the files is literally at the other end of the world (in case this matters)

Comment: use ADO (ADODB), very popular and quite reliable technique for retrieving data from csv files. I don't provide you any link for how to do it because it's so popular that you can easily find lots of information in google and here in SO. maybe one link will be useful to construct correct `ConnectionString` (which makes some problems for beginners): [www.ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Hey, thanks. Had a quick run through google and found promising code pieces